# Couldn't click on element by using the xpath with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying out the selenium framework to learn something about the web browser automation. Therefore, I decided to build an Audi model...

My code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
chrome_driver.get("https://www.audi.de/de/brand/de/neuwagen.html")

# choose A3 model
chrome_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="list"]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a[2]').click()

# choose sedan version
WebDriverWait(chrome_driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="a3limo"]/div/a'))).click()

# start model configuration
WebDriverWait(chrome_driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a'))).click()

# choose the s-line competition package
WebDriverWait(chrome_driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span/span'))).click()

# accept the s-line competition package
WebDriverWait(chrome_driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/ul[2]/li[2]/a'))).click()
```

Now, the code fail already on the line `start model configuration` (see "Konfiguration starten" button on webpage https://www.audi.de/de/brand/de/neuwagen/a3/a3-limousine-2019.html). The xPath must be correct and the element should also be visible, so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post the exception which you are getting

Comment: I'm getting the timeout exception:  raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work for me. I have added waits for elements and used a simulated click of the element via javascript.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://www.audi.de/de/brand/de/neuwagen.html'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-filterval="a3"]'))).click()
d.get(WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#a3limo .mf-model-details a'))).get_attribute('href'))
element = WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title="Konfiguration starten"]')))
d.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: While this might work you should clarify (as OP is newbie to automation) WHY this code works and WHY in your browser-automation you actually do no clicks at all

Answer (score 2):

Actually required link becomes visible only if to scroll page down.

Try to use this piece of code to click link:

```
configuration_start = chrome_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Konfiguration starten"]')
chrome_driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', configuration_start)    
configuration_start.click()
```

As navigation panel has fixed position it might overlap target link, so you can change navigation panel style before handling link:

```
nav_panel = chrome_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-module="main-navigation"]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.position = "absolute";', nav_panel)
```

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a x-cq-linkchecker="skip" class="nm-pageOpen nm-intro-icon" href="/de/brand/de/neuwagen/a3/a3-limousine-2019/linien-pakete.html" data-link-pattern="/de/brand/de/neuwagen/a3/a3-limousine-2019/linien-pakete" title="Konfiguration starten">...</a> is not clickable at point (152, 39). Other element would receive the click: <label class="nm-navigation-toggle-label "

Comment: With the code above, it works only sometimes but not always.

Comment: @PythonNoob , Works fine for me, but OK, I'll try to check it again. Also try to add `chrome_driver.maximize_window()` right after `chrome_driver.get("https://www.audi.de/de/brand/de/neuwagen.html")`

Comment: Nope, didn't work either. The page scrolls down to "Modellhistorie" "Zubehörfinder" "Audi News", so that the "Konfiguration starten" is not visible... strange.

Comment: It works, if I scroll like: chrome_driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 30)"). But thats not great...

Comment: Thanks Andresson, your updated code works also fine. So, which solution is preferrable, yours or QHarrs? And why?

Comment: @PythonNoob , this depends on your goal. If your goal is web-scraping then QHarrs answer is better, but IMHO Selenium shouldn't be used for web-scraping. If you want to simulate user-like behavior then this answer is closer.. But to make it even more *human* you might need to do `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys` and add `configuration_start.send_keys(Keys.UP)` before `configuration_start.click()`

Comment: Ok... Thanks for the explanation!